# Magento2 System configruation

Tags: magento2, image, system-configuration

[image]I upgraded my magento2.2.8 to 2.2.3 after that I open system configuration and try to open configuration but some configuration shows a blank page and some option showing normal.

Comment: If it worked, mark my answer as solved an upvote pls:)

Comment: <![CDATA[<img src="https://meetanshi.com/media/logo.png" alt="Meetanshi" height="20" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>]]> this is my code

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to say.

Comment: see after webkul my code and in my system xml <![CDATA[<img src="meetanshi.com/media/logo.png" alt="Meetanshi" height="20" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>]]>

Answer (score 0):

In your meetanshi module, image is missing you can solve this by following this:
Search this url in your `system.xml` or in your whole folder via `Sublime Text editor` and comment it.

Url: "`https://meetanshi.com/media/logo.png`"

**Updated:**

Run `composer update` command and then check, 
if not solved then recreate vendor folder by running this command `composer install`.

Please check this link for more help: [github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25403](http://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25403)

Comment: no this is sales > Tax area

Comment: my question is not this my question is i open some configratutions but all blank

Comment: please disable meetanshi module once and then check.

Comment: some third party/custom `system.xml` module configuration is wrong that's why you are facing this

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Vertex\Tax\Model\FlexField\FlexFieldProcessableAttribute::setLabel() must be of the type string, null give

Comment: Could you please share code of this file?
or check the file, `setLabel()` function.

Comment: ok but its look like magento2.3.3 issue

Comment: yes, I saw this now. You can run `composer update` command and then check, if not solved then recreate vendor folder by running this command `composer install`.
Please check this link for more help: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25403

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101162/discussion-between-temper-and-imtiazau).